# Spanish IDs: NIF, NIE, CIF validators in grails

Tags: validation, grails, groovy

I was looking for a validator for Spanish IDs like NIE, NIF or CIF, but I was unable to find one written in `Groovy`. That is why I am here. I have this code in javascript (http://www.yporqueno.es/blog/as3-validar-nif-cif-y-nie) as an illustration of how to do it. Did someone already transcripted it to `Groovy`?

Comment: are you having a specific problem?

Comment: Do you need the code in a groovy way or a field gorm validator for each?

Comment: There is no problem, I just want to share my code to internet and the groovy comunity.

Comment: If you want to share your code, as you say, here's how to do so on Stack Overflow, fitting with the Q&A format. (1) Ask a question that _is a question_; present a problem that people will recognize, then (2) post an answer to your own question, explaining how your library or utility solves the problem. Be very clear about your association with the thing you're promoting.

Comment: Take a look to the new [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64242155/2835520), it is more organized

Answer (score 1):

This is my class:

```
class TestDniService {
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
public Boolean isNif(String a) {
    int numero
    String dni=a.toUpperCase();
  //  def letra = dni.substring(dni.length())
    try{
        println"try "+dni.substring(0,dni.length()-1)
        numero =dni.substring(0,dni.length()-1).toInteger()
    }catch (NumberFormatException num){
        return false
    }
    String let = dni.substring(dni.length()-1)
    let=let.toUpperCase();
    numero=numero%23;
    String letra='TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKET';
    String lletra =letra.charAt(numero);
    return (lletra == let);//devuelve true o false
}//End isNif

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
public Boolean isNie(String a) {
    String dni=a.toUpperCase();
    String pre=dni.substring(0,1);
    String prev="0";
    if (pre=="X") {
        prev="0";
    } else if (pre == "Y") {
        prev="1";
    } else if (pre == "Z") {
        prev="2";
    }
    String numero = prev.toString()+dni.substring(1,dni.length()).toString()
    return isNif(numero);//una vez tratamos el NIE lo comprovamos como un NIF
}//End isNie

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
public Boolean isCif(String cif) {
    println"CIF inicial "+cif
    def pares = 0;
    def impares = 0;
    def suma;
    def ultima;
    def unumero;
    def uletra = ["J", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"]
    def xxx;

    String texto=cif.toUpperCase()
    if (!texto ==~ /^[ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQS]\d{7}[0-9,A-J]$/) {
        return false;
    }

    ultima = texto.substring(8,9)
    pares = texto.substring(2,3).toInteger()+texto.substring(4,5).toInteger()+texto.substring(6,7).toInteger()

    for (int cont = 1 ; cont <= 7 ; cont++){
        xxx = 2 * texto.substring(cont,cont+1).toInteger()
        if (xxx > 9) while (xxx > 9){
            xxx =  xxx.toString().substring(0,1).toInteger()+ xxx.toString().substring(1,2).toInteger()
        }
        impares += xxx
        cont++
    }

    suma = (pares + impares).toString();
    unumero = suma.substring(suma.length() - 1,suma.length()).toInteger()
    unumero = (10 - unumero).toString();
    if (unumero.toInteger() == 10) unumero = 0;
    if ((ultima.toString() == unumero.toString()) || (ultima == uletra[unumero.toInteger()]))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}//End isCif

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
public int testAll(String dni) {
    String cadena = dni.toUpperCase();//convertimos a mayusculas
    String pre= cadena.substring(0,1);//extraemos el primer digito o letra
    if (pre=="X"||pre=="Y"||pre=="Z") {//Si el primer digito es igual a X,Y o Z entonces es un NIE
        if (isNie(dni)) {//llamamos a la funcion testNIE(); pasandole por parametro el dni. Devolvera true o false
            return 1;//Si es true devolvemos 1, 1 = NIE correcto.
        } else {
            return -1;//Si es false devolvemos -1, -1 = NIE incorrecto.
        }
    } else {//Si no es un NIE comprovamos si es un CIF
        if (pre ==~ (/[ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSUVW]/)) {//Si la primera letra de la cadena coincide con alguna del patron letrasCIF entonces es un CIF
            if (isCif(dni)) {//llamamos a la funcion testCIF(); pasandole por parametro el dni. Devolvera true o false
                return 2;//Si es true devolvemos 2, 2 = CIF correcto.
            } else {
                return -2;//Si es false devolvemos -2, -2 = CIF incorrecto.
            }
        } else {//Si no es un CIF comprovamos si es un NIF
            if (pre ==~ (/[1234567890]/)) {//Si el primer digito de la cadena coincide con el patron numerosNIF entonces es un NIF
                if (isNif(dni)) {//llamamos a la funcion testNIF(); pasandole por parametro el dni. Devolvera true o false
                    return 3;//Si es true devolvemos 3, 3 = NIF correcto.
                } else {
                    return -3;//Si es false devolvemos -3, -3 = NIF incorrecto.
                }
            } else {//Si tampoco es un NIF entonces no es un dni valido de ningun tipo
                //si no es ninguno devolvemos 0
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}//End function test


}
```

I wish it will help anyone.

Answer provided by [@gsan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5393947/gsan)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example working in production:

**Imagine a `User` class with this fields:**

```
class User implements Serializable {
    String documentNumber
    DocumentType documentType

    static constraints = {
        documentNumber (blank: false, nullable: true, unique: true, validator: { val, obj ->
            //Provide a documentType and the documentNumber to the validate method
            return DocumentType.validateDocument(DocumentType.get(obj.properties['documentType'].toString()), (String)val)
        })
        documentType (blank: false, nullable: true)
    }
}
```

**Here is the utility class:**

*Take a look to `static boolean validateDocument (DocumentType type, String value)`*

```
public enum DocumentType implements org.springframework.context.MessageSourceResolvable {
    CIF('CIF'),
    NIF('NIF'),
    DNI('DNI'),
    NIE('NIE'),
    PASSPORT('Passport')

    String id

    DocumentType(String id) {
        this.id = id
    }

    static DocumentType get(String id) {
        values().find { it.id == id }
    }

    public Object[] getArguments() { [] as Object[] }

    public String[] getCodes() { ["documentType." + name()] as String[] }

    public String getDefaultMessage() { name() }

    @Override
    String toString() {
        return this.id
    }

    /** Utilities **/
    static def CIF_REGEX = /[ABCDEFGHJNPQRSUVW]{1}[0-9]{7}[ABCDEFGHJNPQRSUVW0-9]{1}$/
    static def NIF_REGEX = /[0-9]{8}[A-Z]{1}$/
    static def DNI_REGEX = NIF_REGEX
    static def NIE_REGEX = /[XYZ]{1}[0-9]{7}[A-Z]{1}$/
    static def PASSPORT_REGEX = /^([ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSUVW])(\d{7})([0-9A-J])$/

    static String validationChars = "TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE"

    static boolean validateCIF (String value) {
        if ( (value =~ CIF_REGEX) ) {
            //calculamos el numero de control
            int A = 0, B = 0, C = 0
            String middleNumbers = value.substring(1, 8)
            Integer controlNumber = 0

//            A = Character.getNumericValue(middleNumbers.charAt(1)) + Character.getNumericValue(middleNumbers.charAt(3)) + Character.getNumericValue(middleNumbers.charAt(5))

            for (int i = 1; i < middleNumbers.length(); i += 2) {
                A += Integer.parseInt(middleNumbers.substring(i, i + 1));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < middleNumbers.length(); i += 2) {
                Integer aux = Integer.parseInt(middleNumbers.substring(i, i + 1)) * 2;
                if (aux.toString().length() > 1) {
                    aux = Integer.parseInt(aux.toString().substring(0, 1)) + Integer.parseInt(aux.toString().substring(1, 2));
                }
                B += aux;
            }

            C = (A + B)
            controlNumber = 10 - (C % 10)

            String finalChar = Character.toString( value.charAt(8) )
            String controlCharacter = Character.toString( (char)(64 + controlNumber) )

            println controlNumber.toString()
            println Character.toString( (char)(64 + controlNumber) )
            println finalChar

            if( controlCharacter == finalChar ){
                return true
            } else {
                controlNumber = controlNumber == 10 ? 0 : controlNumber
                if ( controlNumber.toString() == finalChar ) {
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    static boolean validateNIF (String value) {
        if ( (value =~ NIF_REGEX) ) {
            int position = ( Integer.parseInt( value.substring(0, 8) ) ) % 23
            char letter = validationChars.charAt( position )
            if(letter == value.charAt(8)){
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    static boolean validateDNI (String value) {
        return validateNIF(value)
    }

    static boolean validateNIE (String value) {
        if ( (value ==~ NIE_REGEX) ) {
            value = value.replace( 'X','0' )
            value = value.replace( 'Y','1' )
            value = value.replace( 'Z','2' )
            return validateDNI (value)
        }
        return false
    }

    static boolean validatePassport (String value) {
        //La validación de pasaporte depende de cada pais
        return true
    }

    static boolean validateDocument (DocumentType type, String value) {
        boolean result = true
        if (value != null && value != "") {
            value = value.toUpperCase().trim()

            switch (type) {
                case CIF:
                    result = validateCIF (value)
                    break;
                case NIF:
                case DNI:
                    result = validateNIF (value)
                    break;
                case NIE:
                    result = validateNIE (value)
                    break;
                case PASSPORT:
                    result = validatePassport (value)
                    break;
            }

            if (!result) {
                println "type " + type
                println "value " + value
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe it's worth modifying your original answer to avoid ambiguosity

Comment: I know, but the original answer was provided in the question, I moved it but it’s not mine.